# Where would the question "Roughly how many people are typically on the seas at one time?" be on-topic?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there a Stack Exchange site where the following question would be on-topic?

> I was thinking about the reasons why NASA launches rockets by the coast, and one of them is that the ocean has less people on it than land. So that got me thinking, "Roughly how many people are typically on the seas at one time?"

Apparently GIS and Earth Science aren't the right places for this question.

Comment: There's a related post on [our Space-Sciences stack](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/35553/does-the-us-navy-guard-spacex-drone-ships-and-make-sure-bad-actors-dont-abscond) about Space-X and if the navy gets involved in safety procedures, so maybe there. Take their tour, read their help centre etc..

Comment: I don't know where best to ask, but you might want to take a look at https://www.quora.com/How-many-people-are-at-sea-at-any-given-time?share=1

Comment: Note that most sites on SE would require you to add some (basic) research to your post. What did you find out so far (from a Google search or similar)?